# Is the target vertex of an edge stored differently than the same vertex in the graph's vertex set?

Tags: java, graph-theory, vertex, jgrapht

I seem to have come across a non-intuitive discrepancy between how vertexes are stored in Jgrapht graphs (in this case a SimpleDirectedGraph) in the vertexSet, vs. how they are stored as the target of an edge (see below for my usage of getEdgeTarget). I had thought they were identical - i.e. they point to the same object (a SteveVertex in this case) and have the same hash code - but they seem to be located in different places somehow, per symptom below.

When my code below comes across a loop, in which it encounters the original start vertex as the target of an edge, it does not show this vertex as having been visited, even though the hashCode (SteveVertex@vertex1) is identical to the first entry of the vertexSet which DOES show the vertex as having been visited.

```
private static SimpleDirectedGraph<SteveVertex, DefaultEdge> graph;

private static void SteveDepthFirstSearch(SteveVertex startVertex)
 {
     if (!startVertex.visited()) {
         startVertex.visit();
         for (DefaultEdge e : graph.outgoingEdgesOf(startVertex))   
             SteveDepthFirstSearch(graph.getEdgeTarget(e));

         startVertex.setFinishOrder(counter);
         counter++;
     }

 }


public static void main(String[] args) {  

    ...

    for (SteveVertex v: graph.vertexSet())
        SteveDepthFirstSearch(v);

    ...

}
```